# unlocker software website virus message

Tags: malware

Visiting Unlocker software's download page, `http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/`, via Google search gave me the following in Internet Explorer:

> Reported Unsafe Website: Navigation Blocked
>
> This website has been reported as unsafe
>   [..]
>   This website has been reported to Microsoft for containing threats to your computer that might reveal personal or financial information.

[image]

Does Unlocker have trojans/malware?

Comment: @krishna, I don't think you can say *it's an issue in IE only*. True, only IE reports it today. So, maybe Microsoft is just wrong. Or, like I wrote: maybe their analysis is more recent than Google's (which is used in Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

First of all: don't ignore the warning, even when other browsers don't find anything suspicious (yet). **When you can wait, then just wait some days until the warning is no longer shown!**

What you're seeing Microsoft nowadays calls [SmartScreen](http://www.microsoft.com/security/filters/smartscreen.aspx) ("Phishing Filter" in IE7; [technical details](http://www.carbonwind.net/blog/post/2009/09/15/IE8-SmartScreen-Filter-and-TMG-Beta-3-URL-Filtering(using-Microsoft-Reputation-Service-Beta)-Whate28099s-inside-SSL(e2809cquery-traffice2809d).aspx)). There's a "More information" link, that you can safely click. You can also get this information [manually](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/SmartScreen-Filter-frequently-asked-questions):

> - Go to a website that you want to check.
> - Click the Safety button, point to SmartScreen Filter, and then click Check This Website.

IE uses some Microsoft database of bad websites. More of such databases exist. Like, though not specialized in all malware, [PhishTank](http://www.phishtank.com/) does not yield results for `ccollomb.free.fr`. Google's [Safe Browsing](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://ccollomb.free.fr) (as used in Firefox as well) does not find issues either, but: "*The last time Google visited this site was on 2009-09-20*". And [StopBadware.org](http://stopbadware.org/home/reportsearch) does not have the site listed either.

Still: *maybe* Microsoft found some recent (new) threat, or maybe it found some threat at some other subdomain of `free.fr` and hence blocks all of that domain?

Note that even official websites might be compromised with malware, even when the website owner does not know about that.

So: click that "More information" link, it will tell you *a bit* more.

(**If anyone knows of some website at which one can see what Microsoft has recorded about some URL: please tell us!**)

Comment: @krishna, I don't think you can say *it's an issue in IE only*. True, only IE reports it today. Maybe Microsoft is wrong. Or, like I wrote: maybe their analysis is more recent than Google's (which I think is used in Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Its not complaining about Unlocker, but the Website itself is known to serve malware, the website owner may or may not be aware of this fact. Websites get compromised by hackers occasionally and serve malware just by visiting the site, or that site has been reported wrongfully. I get no such error using Chrome browser.

.

Answer (score -2):

Using Firefox with above link gives no problems. Although Unlocker by design can be seen as a malware tool, as it can unlock files currently in use and system files and delete rename them.

If you are still having trouble witht he download, use this link

http://www.2shared.com/file/9073650/671f81fd/unlocker188.html

Comment: These kind of things are not related to a browser. True, only IE reports it today. So, maybe Microsoft is wrong. Or: maybe their analysis is just more recent than Google's (which I think is used in Firefox).